# How can I define the type of an XmlSerializer by the type of a record object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Problem with the code below, on this line:

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(????));
```

I want the type to be define by the record object, can I do that?

```
public void ConvertRecordObjectToXML(object RecordObject, out string XML) 
{
    string xml = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        string XmlizedString = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(????)); // <---- ?????
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        x.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, RecordObject);
        memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
        XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        XML = XmlizedString;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e);
        xml = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(RecordObject.GetType());
```

Answer (score 7):

Every object inherits the method GetType() from Object, so you should be able to use:

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(RecordObject.GetType());
```

The C# **typeof** keyword takes the class name and yields an object of type Type. GetType() yields the same thing, but operates on an instance instead.

Comment: +1 for an answer with *explanation*, rather than just a line of code.